# Strong maximum principle for heat equation. Positivity of solution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, heat-equation

I have a non-negative solution $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1) \cap H^1(0,T;(H^1)')$ of the heat equation
$$u_t-\Delta u =0$$
on bounded $C^1$ domain $\Omega$, with the boundary condition
$$\frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial \nu(x)} = a(t,x) - b(t,x)u(t,x)$$
on $\partial\Omega$, with initial data $u(0) = u_0$.

I have that $u_0 >0 $ a.e. and also bounded from abve. Furthermore, $a$ and $b$ are bounded from above a.e. and $a, b \geq 0$ a.e.

Can I deduce that $u$ is actually strictly positive? I.e. $u > 0$ a.e.?? Another problem i have is I am not sure that solutions are in in $C^2$ (which seems to be necessary to apply the maximum principles).

I tried searching for strong maximum principles but I couldn't see one that I could apply for this problem.

Comment: Are you willing to assume that $a$ is differentiable wrt time?

Comment: @DelioMugnolo Sure if it helps.

Comment: One way to get this (possibly overkill) is from the parabolic Harnack inequality.

Comment: @NateEldredge The problem is that I need $u \in C^{1,2}((0,T)\times \Omega)$ to apply max principle/Harnack which I don't see how to obtain.

Answer (score 2):

Your conjecture is correct, but the answer is going to be somewhat technical.

First of all, we are going to make the Ansatz that the solution is actually smoother wrt time (this will be justified a posteriori), so that the boundary condition can be differentiated wrt to time to yield the dynamic b.c.
$$\frac{\partial Lu}{\partial t}(t,x)=a(t,x)$$
where the boundary operator $L$ is defined by
$$Lu(t,x):=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(t,x)+b(t,x)u(t,x).$$
In this way, you can turn your problem into an abstract Cauchy problem
$$
\frac{d\mathcal u}{d t}(t)={\mathcal A}{\mathcal u}(t)+\Phi(t)
$$
where $\mathcal A$ is the operator matrix
$$
\mathcal A:=\begin{pmatrix}\Delta & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
with domain
$$
D(\mathcal A):=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}u\\ Lu\end{pmatrix}:u\in H^\frac{3}{2}(\Omega):\Delta u\in L^2(\Omega) \right\}
$$
and the inhomogeneous term is
$$
\Phi(t):=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ a(t,\cdot)\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, you are in the setting of the Klaus-Jochen Engel's theory of *one-sided coupled operator matrices* and you can apply a result - essentially due to Engel, but you can find it in a ready-to-use-version in an old paper by Kramar and myself (Proposition 8.10 in "Theory and applications of one-sided coupled operator matrices", 2003) that claims that positivity (and in fact irreducibility) of the semigroup $e^{t\mathcal A}$ generated by $\mathcal A$ follows from positivity (and in fact irreducibility) of the semigroup generated by $\Delta$ with homogeneous Robin boundary conditions plus the strong maximum principle that holds for the Helmholtz equation with homogeneous Robin boundary conditions. (If you are not very familiar with the theory of operator semigroups: positivity and irreducibility of the semigroup generated by $\mathcal A$ correspond to an affirmative answer to your question in the case $a\equiv 0$.)
(Everything so far is precisely true in the one-dimensional case: in the $n$-dimensional case you need a slight generalization of Engel's theory presented in a more recent paper by myself, "Asymptotics of semigroups generated by operator matrices", 2014.)

Now, validity of your conjecture simply follows from the Duhamel formula that tells you that
$$
{\mathcal u}(t)=e^{t\mathcal A}{\mathcal u}_0+\int_0^t e^{(t-s)\mathcal A}\Phi(s)\ ds\ .
$$

Comment: Thank you. I will need time to take a look at the papers you cited but I think you need to change $a$ to $a'$ in your displayed equations.

Comment: @ChristopherSail You are right! And, unfortunately, this actually means that I did not adressed *your* question (case of $a\ge 0$), but rather the question of what happens if $a$ is monotonically increasing in time.

Comment: Ah that's a shame. Do you happen to know if the solution $u \in C^{1,2}((0,T)\times \Omega)$ (once differentiable in $t$ and twice in $x$)? I already know that $u \in C^0((0,T]\times \bar \Omega)$. I just need the additional differentiability in order to apply the strong max principle, which would give me the result.

Comment: Well, $e^{t\mathcal A}$ is analytic, therefore so is $u$ wrt time; but when it comes to its space regularity, the solution is a priori only in the domain of $\Delta^k$ ($\Delta$ being the distributional Laplacian *without* b.c.), so one cannot apply any boundary regularity result. I am pretty sure $u$ is $C^\infty$ wrt space on compact subsets of $\Omega$, but I cannot go further.

Comment: Hello every one. Mr Mugnolo I have a similar question, can we prove the positivity of the solution of heat equation with dynamic bounday conditions. $$u_t=\Delta u- p(x)u$$ and $$u_t=\Delta_\Gamma u - \partial_\nu u -q(x) u,$$ where the potentials $p,q$ are positive. Thank you for any help.

Comment: @S.Cho Yes, this is known. As long as $p$ is $L^\infty$, an easy way to see this is to invoke Theorem 3.6 in https://ejde.math.txstate.edu/Volumes/2006/118/mugnolo.pdf
(formally speaking, you have to work with a slightly different sesquilinear form, where you have added the term $\int_\Omega p u\bar{v} dx$, but it's very easy to see that the proof of Theorem 3.6 goes through.)

Comment: Thank you for the valuable paper, Yes you're right, I had the same idea, just at the beginning I proved the positivity when $p=q=0$, so that I tryed to obtain the desired result by perturbation argument but I don't get the result. Can we do this or it is necessary to change the sesquilinear form from the beginning.

Comment: @S.Cho I haven't checked the details, but I'm almost sure a perturbation argument should do. Basically, you consider the operator matrix featuring the terms $p$ and $q$: this is a bounded, positive operator, so by the Dyson-Phillips series representation of the perturbed semigroup you get positivity again.

Comment: The operator matrix is with $-p$ and $-q$, then it is in fact negative.

Comment: Are $p>0$ and $q>0$? Ok, nevermind, then just apply Trotter-Kato. The semigroups generate by the operator matrix featuring $p$, $q$ is positive. But again, this is unnecessarily complicated. It's much easier to work with forms.

Comment: Is it necessary to assume that $p>0$ and $q>0$ or juste $p, q\geq 0$ ? as you said  the semigroup generated by the operator matrix featuring p, q is positive (by form argument) and then we apply Trotter product formula (where the second operator is bounded).

Comment: In fact, I really want to work with the form without perturbation, but my operator $A$ associated to the system is defined on $\{(u,v)\in H^2(\Omega)\times H^2(\Gamma) : u|_\Gamma =v\}$, and to identify my operator with the operator $A_1$ associated to the form I can't prove that $D(A_1) \subset D(A)$. This is why I'm trying to use perturbation argument.

Comment: @S.Cho I don't quite understand why you can't work with forms if you are dealing with the operator matrix whose leading term entries are a Laplacian on $L^2(\Omega)$ and a Laplace-Beltrami on $L^2(\Gamma)$: this has been done in several papers already. Anyway: a _diagonal_ operator matrix generates a positive semigroup iff its entries are real-valued. Their sign does not play a role, just like in the scalar case.

Comment: The problem is as in my comment above, the old papers considers the maximal domain and not identify it as in my case. Okey I will try with forms, it seems easy to me. What about the fact you mentioned if $p>0$ and $q>0$, what we can do with this ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: P.S my operator is not diagonal $$\mathcal A:=\begin{pmatrix}\Delta-p & 0\\ -\partial_\nu & \Delta_\Gamma- q\end{pmatrix}
$$ with $$D(\mathcal A):=\{(u,v)\in H^2(\Omega)\times H^2(\Gamma) : u|_\Gamma =v\}
.$$

Comment: @S.Cho As I said: it's not your matrix $\mathcal A$ that is diagonal (it wouldn't be bounded anyway), but the operator matrix $\begin{pmatrix}-p  & 0\\ 0 & -q\end{pmatrix}$: the latter defines a bounded operator which in turn generates the positive sgr $\begin{pmatrix}e^{-tp}  & 0\\ 0 & e^{-tq}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @S.Cho Anyway: With your domain, the operator $\mathcal A$ is not closed.
Positivity of the semigroug generated its closure is a special case of Theorem 3.6 in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3580

Comment: Why $\mathcal{A}$ is not closed ? I think that \mathcal{A} is the operator associated with the form with gradients adding the term $\int_\Omega p u\bar{v} dx + \int_\Gamma q u\bar{v} ds$

Comment: I found that $\mathcal{A}$ is the operator assciated with the form. Then it is closed. Is that true ?

Comment: How do you show that if $(u,v)$ is in $D(\mathcal A)$, then $u\in H^2(\Omega)$? Since $\Delta u$ is only defined in the sense of distributions, $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ will in general only be true under very strong assumptions on $\Omega$.

Comment: Yes, in my case $\Omega$ is smooth enough (at least $C^2$). I used the elleptic regularity of Laplace and Laplace-Biltrami operators. What do you think ?

Comment: Yes, then everything is fine. If the boundary is less regular you'll probably end up with a larger domain.

Comment: I'm sorry for the long discussion. Thank you so much.